# How to add element for element in a list of list?

Tags: python, list

Sorry to ask, probabily this is a simple question but I can't find a solution.

I have a list of lists, like this:

```
my_list = [['ba', 'da'], ['ra', 're'], ['ta', 'ma'], ]
```

the number of list is variable (3 in the example) but the lenght is the same for all of them (2 in the example).

I want:

```
new_list = ['barata', 'darema']
```

where

```
new_list[i] = my_list[0][i] + my_list[1][i] + my_list[2][i]
```

Comment: Can you include your attempt that came the closest to being what you need?

Comment: Can you please clarify this "I have string, not integer but probabily is the same"?

Comment: @Andreas In my list I haven't integer (like in my example) but string. I hoped to be more clear using integer but probabily not because the solution don't works (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str')

Comment: @wwii not like that because I have string

Comment: `I hoped to be more clear using integer...` - You should always include a [mcve] that faithfully represents your problem.

Comment: @wwii sorry, I thinked it was faithfull

Comment: Other duplicate for edited question - [Element wise concatenate multiple lists (list of list of strings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56479890/element-wise-concatenate-multiple-lists-list-of-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_list = [['ba', 'da'], ['ra', 're'], ['ta', 'ma'], ]
[''.join(t) for t in zip(*my_list)]
```

Gives:

```
['barata', 'darema']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip` to pack the unpacked items from  `my_list`.

```
my_list = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [3, 2]]

my_list=list(map(sum,zip(*my_list)))

print(my_list)
```

---

output

```
[5,6]
```

---

if elements are `str` then use the below code.

```
my_list = [['ba', 'da'], ['ra', 're'], ['ta', 'ma'], ]

my_list=list(map(''.join,zip(*my_list)))

print(my_list)
```

---

output

```
['barata', 'darema']
```

Comment: You don't have to use list() on zip().

Comment: @AndreasK. Yes, I realized it map just needs an iterable and edited it long back by the way.

Comment: @Ch3steR thank you for your answer but for my fault it doesn't work: I have strings, not integers so it gives me this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @fabio You edited the question. This answer was if elements were integers. I'll edit and add for `strings` too